# ALSA and PyAudio

Tags: python, alsa, pyaudio

I'm writing a simple application and I need to read from the microphone, this is my program (it's just a start to understand how pyAudio works):

```
CHUNK = 256  
FORMAT = pyaudio.paInt16 #paInt8 
CHANNELS = 2 
RATE = 16000  #sample rate RECORD_SECONDS = 2

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser() 
parser.add_argument("fname", help="name of the file") 
args = parser.parse_args() 
p = pyaudio.PyAudio() 
WAVE_OUTPUT_FILENAME = "./Scrivania/audioxMarco/"+args.fname+".wav"

stream = p.open(format=FORMAT,
                channels=CHANNELS,
                rate=RATE,
                input=True,
                frames_per_buffer=CHUNK) #buffer

print("* recording")

frames = []

for i in range(0, int(RATE / CHUNK * RECORD_SECONDS)):
    data = stream.read(CHUNK)
    frames.append(data) # 2 bytes(16 bits) per channel

print("* done recording")

stream.stop_stream() 
stream.close() 
p.terminate()
```

I get this warning:

> ALSA lib pcm.c:2266:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.rear
>   ALSA lib pcm.c:2266:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM
>   cards.pcm.center_lfe ALSA lib pcm.c:2266:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate)
>   Unknown PCM cards.pcm.side ALSA lib
>   pcm_route.c:867:(find_matching_chmap) Found no matching channel map
>   ALSA lib pcm_route.c:867:(find_matching_chmap) Found no matching
>   channel map ALSA lib pcm_route.c:867:(find_matching_chmap) Found no
>   matching channel map ALSA lib pcm_route.c:867:(find_matching_chmap)
>   Found no matching channel map connect(2) call to
>   /dev/shm/jack-0/default/jack_0 failed (err=No such file or directory)
>   attempt to connect to server failed

What does it mean?

In the end the programs does what it must, but I have some issues with the frame size.

If I print `len(frames)`, I get 1024, when it should be at least 4096 (2 bytes for the format, x2 with the channel, for 1024).

Comment: Try setting channel to mono. eg `CHANNELS = 1`

Comment: I think you observed ‘len(frames[0])’. In that case, 1024 is correct.

Comment: The warnings are harmless unless you records more than 3 channels. They are assigning warnings, such as no device output channel for the rear etc.

Comment: Thanks, i have just one more question: The byte-order is little-endian or big-endian?